# Optimal Hosting for a Statistical Analysis Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, r, cluster-computing, statistics

I am developing a web app that performs regression analysis on user data.

on the backend, **RoR** is taking care of application logic, and all statistical analysis is done by **R** (since Ruby has poor stat packages).

Given that both R and RoR are *single-threaded*, and that the app is expected to be used concurrently by several users - I need your advice on the optimal configuration.

for example: should I run the R and RoR machines on separate instances and have RoR communicate with R via REST? run both on the same machine which can be clustered? use Revolution Analytics?

what would be a good hosting configuration to allow scalability of my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a proxy to communicate to multiple webservers, and in turn each of these webservers communicates via a proxy to several R_servers.  To have the proxy servers balance the load, you can look into something like Nginx's upstream directives.

The diagram below shows 3 webservers (which are exact clones of each other), and 3 R_servers (which are exact clones of each other).  Use however many you need, since it's easy to add/remove the webservers or R_servers to scale horizontally.

```
        webserver1           R_server1
      /            \       /
proxy - webserver2 - proxy - R_server2
      \            /       \
        webserver3           R_server3
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Rserve](http://rforge.net/Rserve) which, when hosted on Linux, forks off a new instance on every connection.

Connection is over the network, and there are Ruby clients available [as indicated by a Google search](http://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#hl=en&safe=off&nord=1&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=ruby%20client%20Rserve&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=5798bb38410649e2&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1280&bih=926)